# How many solana transaction confirmations are enough to declare a transaction as finalized before it hits 31 and actually finalizes itself?

Tags: nft, web3.js

So i'm messing around with transactions and want to make sure that it goes through before continuing so that i dont end up losing solana as if this were a peer to peer transaction. Waiting for a tx to hit 31 confirmations takes too long and I want to speed it up, so whats a good amt of confirmations for me to declare a transaction as finalized myself to speed up the whole process a tad bit? Thanks.

Comment: this can't really be answered in a general way, it's application specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solana offers three different commitment levels, `finalized`, `confirmed` and `processed`, as described [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment).

A commitment level of `confirmed` is usually considered sufficient unless your existence depends on it. It is usually quite fast, as 1 - 3 seconds or so.

Solana doesn't work with the "number of confirmations" scheme that is used in Ethereum with PoW. The commitment levels are based whether a supermajority of validators has confirmed the transaction (finalized) or includes votes from gossip (inter-validator communication) and replay (confirmed). Therefore, the time to `confirmed` and time to `finalized` can vary.