# Confirmations vs commitment .how to to understand RpcResponse from a confirmation

Tags: transactions, rpc, web3.js, slots

So following the answer from this thread:

[How many solana transaction confirmations are enough to declare a transaction as finalized before it hits 31 and actually finalizes itself?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/716/how-many-solana-transaction-confirmations-are-enough-to-declare-a-transaction-as)

> Solana doesn't work with the "number of confirmations" scheme that is
> used in Ethereum with PoW. The commitment levels are based whether a
> supermajority of validators has confirmed the transaction (finalized)
> or includes votes from gossip (inter-validator communication) and
> replay (confirmed). Therefore, the time to confirmed and time to
> finalized can vary.

and documentation from: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#default

> If commitment configuration is not provided, the node will default to
> "finalized" commitment

On the front-end, when sending transactions like so

```
const signature = await provider.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);
          

          const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(
            {
              blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
              signature,
            }
          );
```

I would get the following RpcResponse object

```
 const confirmationRpcResponse = {
    context: {slot: 150669448}
    value: {err: null}
    }
```

Is my understanding correct, that if I do not provide any commitment (in the **signAndSendTransaction** method) the RPC response **confirmTransaction** gives me information that transaction was finalized and I do not need any more "checking for confirmations", "checking for timestamps" etc. ?

Why does **value** key hold an **err** object and no actual value, like "processed" "finalized" "confirmed" - anything that would be more understandable than just slot and empty err key. How should I understand the response I got?

UPDATE 26.07.2022:

Just got the following error:

> Error: TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature
> mySingature--->qYmvyL9qqsJte2TKXLyu9DZUrjQs9cU9PFVsyvjGM9vd3UykkvbLfLhbRjQqhM4BhRFWM7eW
> has expired: block height exceeded.

When using the above method. So there is definitely something else that has to be done before I can declare a transaction final. Where can I read about it?

UPDATE 27.07.2022:

So yesterday I was getting something from

```
connection.confirmTransaction(
            {
              blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
              signature,
            }
```

Today it doesn't return anything. Just like that. good game well played. Looks like after some time I get:

> Error: TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature
> 56767Ps4Fq4ZCaowEzPxPoNhSEECsw41MebNkSCEcx2ZnWmQr8aCQjTqnArSK7NeCqBXRUehNuiqQk2LRwhym73
> has expired: block height exceeded.

So I guess the network is busy.

> Follow-up after few minutes

https://solana.fm/tx/56767Ps4Fq4ZCaowEzPxPoNhSEECsw41MebNkSCEcx2ZnWmQr8aCQjTqnArSK7NeCqBXRUehNuiqQk2LRwhym73?cluster=devnet-solana

Transaction has been **confirmed, finalized! SuccessFinalizedMaximum Confirmations Achieved!**

Can someone explain that to me?

`signAndSendTransaction(transaction)` -> doesn't return any promise
next
`connection.confirmTransaction` -> return an error that blockheight was exceeded. Then after a while transaction gets included.

How am I supposed to handle this on the front-end...

Answer (score 1):

**Reasons that `confirmTransaction` might throw a block height exceeded error when, in fact, the transaction was confirmed**:

- the signature is *so* old that it’s fallen out of the *status cache*. The confirm method does not search any further back in the ledger than that. Read more [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturestatuses).
- the signature was confirmed *before* you made the call to `confirmTransaction`, so the confirmation code ‘missed’ it. This is a known bug, tracked [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25955).

When the block height passes without `confirmTransaction` having received a notification that the signature was confirmed, for one of the above reasons, you may receive a misleading BlockHeightExceeded error.

Comment: As for the format of the response, where you have a null `err` property, you can read about that here: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#results-31

Comment: Thank you @steveluscher. 

And is there any reason the response object doesn't include property confirmationStatus or confirmations? Could this be also related to the bug https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25955?

Is there any workaround for the confirmTransaction error until the issue gets fixed?

Comment: `confirmations` is nullable. The [docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturestatuses) have this to say about that: “…null if rooted, as well as finalized by a supermajority of the cluster”

Comment: With respect to `confirmationStatus`, the code comments have this to say: “cluster confirmation status, if data available.” Is this an old transaction; one that would have fallen out of the status cache of the RPC you're making the request to?